# Really Long delay on simple update in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a really simple update that for some reason is taking almost 5 secconds to update one row.

The update statement is:

```
UPDATE `li_webs_trans`.`li_sentances` 
SET `target_sentance` = 'вашими пільгами тепер займається відділення Управління соціальної    допомоги та допомоги на дому, вказане нижче.' 
WHERE `trans_id` = '483' 
AND `sentance_id` = '5';
```

The table being updated is:

```
CREATE TABLE `li_sentances` (
`trans_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`sentance_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`eng_sentance` VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
`target_sentance` VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
`traget_lang` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I thought that there may be some indexes updateing, but I checked and there are no indexes on the table. The rest of the database is performing as expected.  The table is not super huge, only 106,000 rows.  Any Idea what could be slowing down the insert?

Comment: you need to put indexes on `trans_id` and `sentance_id`

Comment: That is an extremely scary schema. Why MyISAM and why those outrageously big `VARCHAR` columns? For this you probably want `LONGTEXT`. Also you have zero indexes which will kill performance.

Comment: A composite index on (trans_id,sentance_id) [sic] would probably help. A PRIMARY KEY would be nice too.

Comment: Thanks all of you.  I was planing to do some fulltext searches, but that isn't working out.  I switched to Longtext, Innodb and added the index and we are doing great!

Comment: you define `trans_id` and `sentance_id` as an `int`, but you are updating with a string... This does work, but it can slow down an update. If you are defining it as an int, update/select/insert/delete with an int.